# Cannot install CIVICRM on Drupal 9

Tags: install, drupal-9

I am trying to install CIVICRM on Drupal 9 as per instruction found here https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal9/

When i enter "composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.29'" getting error as below .. how to resolve this issue ?

[root@srv public_html]# composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}:'~5.29'
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Continue as root/super user [yes]? yes
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update civicrm/civicrm-core civicrm/civicrm-packages civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- civicrm/civicrm-core[5.29.0, ..., 5.35.0] require pear/validate_finance_creditcard dev-master -> found pear/validate_finance_creditcard[dev-master] but it does not match your minimum-stability.
- Root composer.json requires civicrm/civicrm-core ~5.29 -> satisfiable by civicrm/civicrm-core[5.29.0, ..., 5.35.0].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Thanks
Jaiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace 5.29 in the instructions with the current version. Right now it's 5.35.

And I thought the docs were updated for this but for drupal 9 you also need to add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` into composer.json.

Also don't run composer as the root user.

Comment: I have done what you suggested and got error 
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.


  [ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(/home/fimember/public_html/vendor/composer/installed.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Jaisal

Comment: If you ran it as root before then that folder is now owned by root, so you'll need to change the owner on everything in the vendor folder. Or just delete it if you're starting from scratch.

Comment: that solution worked!

Comment: Great! Enjoy your civi site!

Answer (score 0):

This issue we blogged about on [Bug in CiviCRM Installer for Drupal 9](https://civihosting.com/blog/bug-in-civicrm-installer-for-drupal-9/) and the basic solution is to run this:

```
composer require pear/validate_finance_creditcard:dev-master
```

before you try to install. Then it works.